# Strings in C Language

Tags: c

How can you code this in C language if the output is like this? I need **strings** format of the code because our topic is **strings**.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() 
{ 
    char my_string[50];

    printf("Enter a word:");
    scanf("%s", my_string);

    printf("Enter a word:");
    scanf("%s", my_string);

    // Some unknown code here...
    // this part is my only problem to solve this.

    getch();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello -> (user input)

World -> (user input)

HWeolrllod -> (result)
```

Comment: It smells like homework. Tag as appropriate

Comment: @Blackbear: Homework tag has been discontinued, sorry pal.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Should Hello be followed by a prompt, then World followed by a prompt? And what is result? :)

Comment: @Binary: See [Is homework an exception?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception). Also: ["So we don’t have to stamp out every iota of meta-tags, we just have to DISCOURAGE it..."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) Jeff himself. Have I missed anything in that debate lately?

Comment: @Skurmedel: it should read two strings and print them interleaved.

Comment: @ruslik: Thanks, you have superior skills of deduction :D The left hand thing is some kind of production then.

Comment: please try something yourself first

Comment: @sbi: *sigh* No I was't aware homework survived the tag cull. I'm glad, I find it a very *useful* tag.

Comment: @Binary: I'm with you there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception/70155#70155

Answer (score 9):

Okay, you need to do some investigating. We don't, as a general rule, do people's homework for them since:

- it's cheating.
- you'll probably get caught out if you copy verbatim.
- it won't help you in the long run at all.

The C library call for user input that you should use is `fgets`, along the line of:

```
char buffer[100];
fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

This will input a string into the character array called buffer.

If you do that with two different buffers, you'll have the strings in memory.

Then you need to create pointers to them and walk through the two strings outputting alternating characters. Pointers are not an easy subject but the following pseudo-code may help:

```
set p1 to address of first character in string s1
set p1 to address of first character in string s1
while contents of p1 are not end of string marker:
    output contents of p1
    add 1 to p1 (move to next character)
    if contents of p2 are not end of string marker:
        output contents of p2
        add 1 to p2 (move to next character)
while contents of p2 are not end of string marker:
    output contents of p2
    add 1 to p2 (move to next character)
```

Translating that into C will take some work but the algorithm is solid. You just need to be aware that a character pointer can be defined with `char *p1;`, getting the contents of it is done with `*p1` and advancing it is `p = p + 1;` or `p1++;`.

Short of writing the code for you (which I'm *not* going to do), there's probably not much else you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
void main()

{

 char my_string1[50],my_string2[50];  int ptr;
 ptr=0;
 printf("Enter a word : ");
 scanf("%s",my_string1);
 printf("enter a word");
 scanf("%s",my_string2);

while(my_string1[ptr]!='\0' && my_string2[ptr]!='\0')
 {
 printf("%c%c",my_string1[ptr],my_string2[ptr]);
 ptr++;
 }


 if(my_string1[ptr]!='\0')
 {
  while(my_string1[ptr]!='\0')
   { printf("%c",my_string1[ptr]);
    ptr++;
   }
 }
else
{
  while(my_string2[ptr]!='\0')
 {printf("%c",my_string2[ptr]);
  ptr++;
  }

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main() 
{ 
       char my_string1[50],my_string2[50];
       int i,l1=1,l2=0;

       printf("Enter a word:");
       scanf("%s", my_string1);

       printf("Enter a word:");
       scanf("%s", my_string2);

       l1=strlen(my_string1); /* Length of 1st string */
       l2=strlen(my_string2); /* Length of 2nd string */
       if(l1==l2)
       {
            for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
            {
                printf("%c%c",my_string1[i],my_string2[i]);
            }
       }
       else
       {
                printf("Length of the entered strings do not match");
       }
}
```

This is your required code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that output needs to be a String containing all chars of User String1 and User String2 one by one...

You can do this like...

```
//add #include<String.h>
int l1=strlen(s1);
int l2=strlen(s2);
if(l1!=l2)
{
    printf("length do not match");
    return 0;
}
char ansstr[l1+l2];
int i,j=0,k=0;
for(i=0;i<l1+l2;i=i+2)
{
    ansstr[i]=s1[j];
    ansstr[i+1]=s2[k];
    j++;
    k++;``
}
//ansstr is your answer
```

Answer (score -4):

Ok, here's your code. Come on guys, if he asked here it means he can't solve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str1[] = "abcdefghijklmopq";
    char str2[] = "jklm";

    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);
    int c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
    int max = (len1 > len2) ? len1 : len2 ;

    char *result = malloc(len1 + len2);

    for(c1 = 0; c1 <= max; c1++) {
        if(c1 < len1)
            result[c2++] = str1[c1];

        if(c1 < len2)
            result[c2++] = str2[c1];
    }

    result[c2] = 0;

    printf("\n%s\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically the loop picks up a character from `str1` and appends it to result. Then it picks a character, which stands in the same position as the first from `str2` and appends it to result, just as before. I increment `c2` by 2 every time because I'm adding 2 chars to `result`. I check if `c1` is bigger that the length of the strings because I want to copy only the characters in the string without the terminating `\0`. If you know that your strings have the same length you can omit these ifs.

Comment: As you're no doubt about to find out, it's considered bad form to give code answers to homework questions :-)

Comment: It is considered bad form, but still an answer.

Comment: Yes, but is it a _useful_ answer? :-) If all it took to get upvotes was an answer of any sort, I'd have a rep well beyond where Skeet currently is.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I agree with the third answer of this question (answer by kop): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception

Comment: @paxdiablo: if he wants can ask and I'll give explanations, but suppose he doesn't want to do his homework and do something funnier. And I'm not here every day to gain reputation and upvotes. ;)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Well, no, but it is as far as I can see correct. Yours is better though, it is more pedagogical. Personally I favour any answer which explains the steps taken in solving the problem, but they are pretty few on this site to be honest.

Comment: for(c1 = 0; c1 <= max; c1++) should be c1<max. You are now copying the null termination accidently in the loop, and then as well add it manually at the end. I'm also not quite sure what this code does... it concaternates one character from str1, then the next one from str2? This whole code makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: #include<stdio.h> #include<stdlib.h> void main() { char my_string[50]; printf("Enter a word:"); scanf("%s",my_string); printf("Enter a word:"); scanf("%s",my_string); blah blah blah (this part is my only problem to solve this.) getch(); }    can anyone help me on that part..i want explanations

Comment: @lundin: it works, try it. it adds to result the c1-th character of both str1 and str2. @bea: i'll edit, give me a minute.

Comment: @BlackBear7: okay, i'll wait for you..format it in c language and make it simple..ty

Comment: @bea: Read my answer. I added some explanations.

Comment: @BlackBear: the dev c++ app says that the str1 and str2 is undeclared..when i declared it and the app says "passing arg 1 of "strlen" makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: @bea: you have to declare str1 and str2 as char[]. Wait, I'll post my complete code.

Comment: @BlackBear: the user should input any word he wants not the programmer..you missed the printf and scanf..i'm i right?

Comment: @bea: yes, you are. ;) just add them.

Comment: @BlackBear: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!! until next time!! :) do u have a facebook? in case i have a question

Comment: @bea: no, I'm sorry. I haven't much free time. ;) but on my profile there's my email, click on my name. By the way, could you please accept my answer? (clicking on the thick to the left

Comment: @BlackBear:oh i see..okay i'll email you if i need your help..by the way,what is your nationality? i already accept your answer.

Comment: @BlackBear: where in your profile did you put your email? i can't find it..really your 16 years old?

Comment: @BlackBear: okay i'll add you..so what is your sex?

Comment: BlackBear, I think you're being chatted up :) LMAO. More seriously you want to be careful putting your email out so publically. A lot of people downvoted you. Some might get so irate at you answering a homework question like this that they'll send you an email bomb or sign you up for tons of junk mail - if the junk mailers don't see your email address first that is. There are automated programs that scour the internet for anything looking like an email address.

Comment: @alastairg: thanks for the advice, but that's not my "confidential" one. ;)

Comment: @BlackBear: ok..you can now delete your email...whats is the meaning of "?"and ":"...?

Comment: @beya14: it's a short way to write an if-clause

Comment: Having taught C++ for years, and earning my money programming together with (hopefully) knowledgeable coworkers for even longer, I wholeheartedly agree with everyone who down-voted you. __May this person one day become your coworker, and sit on your lap all day requiring your help, since he cheated his way through university using the likes of you.__

Comment: @sbi: he's just learning. Maybe he spent all yesterday thinking about it, who knows? And I'm sure even you cheated on homework at least one time, didn't you? ;)

Comment: @BlackBear: The point is that he's not learning. He's just copying. (And with errors, you didn't free your string.)

Comment: @sbi: ok ok, got it. next time I'll give just hints ;)

Comment: Not to worry, if the OP doesn't get found out for plagiarism, at least they'll lose marks for the multiple bugs in the code. Ain't karma sweet? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Unfortunately many universities have turned into machines for getting money. Not every teacher reviews or tests code thoroughly. It's often like "Ohh, it works! Good student, here's your A mark." And then this guy can become a cowoker of one of us.

Comment: @BlackBear: what is the meaning of malloc and strlen? my teacher doesn't taught us well in this and he gave us an assignment..that's why i'm cramming to do the right thing.. even though blackbear gave his code,i'm doing my best to understand it.

Comment: @beya14: strlen() returns the length of a string, and malloc().. well, let's say it makes room for a variable.

Comment: @beiya: If you turn in a solution using `strlen` and `malloc` when you haven't been shown them in class you instructor may ask you about them. It would be a good idea to think about what to do then.

Comment: @sharptooth: When I taught C++, my students, in their third semester, were usually very shocked when I said "I'm sure you got this running somehow, let's skip over the presentation and show me your code". Apparently, my course was the first they had where they had to show their code.